# solving a linearly-constrained sparse linear least-squares problem

Tags: optimization, least-squares, constraints, linear-system

[ question reposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786612/solving-a-linearly-constrained-sparse-linear-least-squares-problem ]

Given the system of equations

$Ax=b$, subject to $Cx\le d$

where $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix (with $n>m$) and is very large and sparse. As an example $A$ can have $3126250\times 2740$ elements. Each row of $A$ has only 4 or 5 non-zero numbers which can only be 1 or -1.

I am on Matlab and I've been using LSQR but I need the inequality constraints to impose monotonicity on $x$.

Can you please advise on any solvers to do this with linear constraints? Is there any implementation on Matlab or C for this?

Comment: Is your problem actually $\min \| Ax - b \|_{2}^{2}$ subject to $Cx \leq d$?

Comment: How big are $n$ and $m$?

Comment: As an example $A$ can have $3126250\times 2740$ elements. I've added more information above. My system is $Ax=b$, right now I am solving it like that yes: $argmin_x ||Ax-b||^2_2$, s.t. $Cx\le d$.

Comment: Are you constraints just of the form $x_{k} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_{i}$, or are there other linear inequalities?

Comment: They are only monotonicity constraints, $x_{i+1}\ge x_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the MATLAB optimization toolbox then this can easily be done using the quadprog() function.  You'd start by writing the objective in quadratic form as

$ \| Ax - b \|_{2}^{2} = x^{T}(A^{T}A)x-2(A^{T}b)^{T}x+b^{T}b$

then multiply to get $P=A^{T}A$ and $q=-2A^{T}b$.  Then your objective is

$f(x)=x^{T}Px+q^{T}x+b^{T}b$

and ready to feed into quadprog().  The $P$ matrix is only 2740 by 2740, so this isn't a very large problem from the point of view of quadprog().

I'm sure there are some free qp solvers for MATLAB if you don't have a copy of the optimization toolbox.

Also note that you may want to reformulate the problem in terms of variables $z_{i}$, where

$x_{1}=z_{1}$

$x_{2}=z_{1}+z_{2}$

$\ldots$

Then you can replace your inequality constraints $Cx \leq d$ with $z \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. MATLAB's quadprog with the active-set algorithm (which is the appropriate for non-convex problems with linear inequality constraints) does not support sparse matrices. I will try that approach where $z_{i+1}=x_{i+1}+x_i$ and report back.

Comment: The $A^{T}A$ matrix is small enough that it doesn't matter much whether you treat it as a sparse matrix (in fact, the matrix will likely be quite dense.)  Just take full(A'*A) to get the $P$ matrix in dense form. Furthermore, the objective function will be convex, since $A^{T}A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: MATLAB's interior-point-convex for quadprog solver is returning "The problem is non-convex". So not sure what is happening there. Furthermore if that's the case, what would be the reason for quadprog to have non-convex algorithms? And yes of course you are right, there is no reason for me to use sparse with $A^T A$. Just as a note, even with a 2740 by 2740, at least with MATLAB algorithms for non-convex problems, this is prohibitively slow.

Comment: That's quite odd.  I'd compute the eigenvalues of $P$ matrix next.  If any of them are significantly negative then you've made a mistake in computing $P$.  Its more likely that you'll find a few eigenvalues that are just barely negative (something like -1.0e-19)  If that's the case, you can just add a small multiple of $I$ to $P$ to restore the positive definiteness.

Comment: The smaller eigenvalue is about -1e-10. I did that identity trick and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This is in indication that $A^{T}A$ is singular- the negative eigenvalue is just the result of round-off error.  This does mean that the solution of the least squares problem is non-unique.  By adding a small multiple of the identity to $P$, you're regularizing the solution with a bias toward $x=0$.

Comment: My problem has inherently multiple solutions. My equations are actualy ratios in a log space to make it a linear system. As such any multiple of a solution is also a solution.

Comment: You might find it useful to pin down the solution by (e.g.) adding an equality constraint $x_{1}=1$.

Comment: Isn't there $\frac{1}{2}$ missing? Because `quadprog` is designed for problems of the form $\frac{1}{2}x^THx+f^Tx$, but the term which is _ready to feet into quadprog()_ is $x^{T}Px+q^{T}x$. The whole thing should be multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$ so that $q$ then is defined as $q=-A^{T}b$ while $P$ remains $P=A^{T}A$, shouldn't it?